# How to remove Measure/mobileOcr/engriks malware?

Tags: malware

My phone is attacked by barrage of error dialogs every 1 second:

> - Unfortunately Measure Has Stopped
> - Unfortunately mobileOcr Has Stopped
> - Unfortunately engriks Has Stopped

It makes the phone so laggy until it restarts by itself. Some other apps also don't work, and it's hard to use the keyboard due to the error dialogs.

I have tried:

- Disabling and uninstalling the apps from Settings
- Installing antiviruses (NQ Mobile Security & Antivirus), but it didn't help either
- Factory reset

I found out that turning off the WiFi (or internet) and restarting the phone prevent the error dialogs to appear, but as soon as I turn it on, they appear again.

Is there a way to remove these malwares?

---

<sup>*This scenario is written based on the post from [AndroidCentral forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/598032-how-do-i-remove-engriks-virus.html) and [Cafe Arjun blog](http://cafearjun.com/2015/10/22/unfortunately-measure-mobileocr-engriks-has-stopped-android-virus/). Original poster didn't face this malware personally</sup>

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP cannot confirm any answers, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I also have an idea!

Buy an SD card (a new one), put it into the mobile phone, and go to settings. Then go to apps and select engriks ... move them to the SD card, and then remove the SD card.

Maybe it works. I still did not try it.